# TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descripton

Tags: sid

When i am tring to access my oracle instance using basic connection type. It gives me an error telling "TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descripton", 
But i can connect to the same user using Sqlplus 
tnsping orcl =

```
    Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhos
    t)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.007gu
    ard.com)))


OK (0 msec)
```

i even tried to use the service name instead of the sid to connect and it doesn't work !
yesterday everything was fine .. i have restarted my laptop and i got this problem .. ( all my oracle services work fine )

Comment: which server are you using

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0
 - 64bit Production

Comment: want to know application / webserver

Comment: wampserver .. but it has nothing to do with this .. because it doesn't connect even when i use oracle sql developer .. it only works on sqlplus ( cmd )

everything was allright yesterday ..

Comment: i have located my problem ..  i have changed my windows Host file yesterday now the agent look for this new localhost C:\Windows\system32>emctl reload agent
EM Configuration issue. \product\11.2.0\dbhome_2/www.*.com_orcl not found.
instead of
product\11.2.0\dbhome_2/localhost_orcl